Design for a Peak Follower for 3-30MHz?
Anyone have suggestions for a broadband (3-30MHz) peak detector? So far I'm working with high-speed op amps such as LMH6628 and AD8092, using a ceramic capacitor to hold the peak charge and a resistor in parallel to discharge. It works, but no single capacitor value works over the full frequency range. Could there be a frequency-compensating design? Perhaps an entirely different approach?
I should add that the goal is to produce a peak-reading LED bar graph that shows the peak voltages for a SSB signal in lieu of an oscilloscope.

Only use NP0 ceramic or metal film caps for S&H, never other ceramics

Change your question to specify slew rate to sample peak and decay rate to hold

Does it need to be precision? If the signal level is a few volts, a simple signal diode will get you as much accuracy as an LED bar graph requires.

Details of what you've tried would help. Schematic, please. Opamps generally don't make good peak detectors: comparators, or even discretes are better.
